# undefined variable user laravel

Tags: laravel, variables, undefined

I load the path from a picture from a database `src="{{ Storage::url($user->avatar) }}"` The image should be displayed on the profile page and in the settings. On the profile page it shows the picture, in the settings I get the error message "undefined variable user". 
how can I define the variable "user"?

```
    class SettingsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      return view('setting')
      ->with('user', $user);
    }

    public function editProfile()
    {
      return view('setting')->with('info', Auth::user()->profile);
    }

    public function updateProfile(Request $r)
    {

      $this->validate($r,[
        'about' => 'required|max:250',
        'webpage' => 'required'
      ]);

      Auth::user()->profile()->update([
        'about' => $r->about,
        'webpage' => $r->webpage
      ]);

      if($r->hasFile('avatar'))

      {
        Auth::user()->update([
          'avatar'=> $r->avatar->store('public/' . Auth::id() . '/avatar')
        ]);
      }

      return back()->with('success', lang::get('messages.profileupdate'));
    }
}
```

Comment: did you pass the user when you returning the view in your controller? Please refer to the official documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers

Comment: i think so: return view("setting", ["user"=>$user]);

Comment: How you are creating the $user?

Comment: i think here is the problem: $user = User;

Comment: Copy/paste some of your controller code for settings page. looks like you forgot to initiate $user variable inside your controller.

Comment: I edited the post and added the code

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments I think that you are missing some basic understanding of how Laravel "works". Please read the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/) and follow the examples.

There is a user specific example with user there in [Controller Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers) at Defining Controllers section.

> [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) is a website with useful tutorials and it is always my recommendation for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

In index() method, you are sending $user to the view without defining it first.

Add **$user = \Auth::user();** before that. See following.

```
class SettingsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user = \Auth::user(); // define user first before sending it to the view      
        return view('setting')
        ->with('user', $user);
    }
```

Comment: If still getting the same error, that means the **user is not logged in**